# Statistical inference in A/B testing: is it enough to compare observed test outcome to control distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, causality, ab-test, causalimpact

I want to run an A/B test to examine the effect of a marketing campaign on revenue. I’m using a synthetic control setup, hence I have to compare the revenue generated by treated units to the counterfactual revenue given by the synthetic control.

One way of assessing if there is a non-random effect of the campaign is to compare the observed revenue under treatment to the distribution of all possible counterfactual revenues (as derived by my counterfactual model). If the observed treatment revenue was in the tail of such distribution (i.e., I get a low p-value), then I would conclude the campaign had an effect. This is the inferential approach adopted, for example, by Google’s library CausalImpact.

I wonder if this is enough, however. The observed revenue in the treated units could have been different from the value actually measured, due to random noise. The above approach does not take into account this uncertainty in observed treatment, but this uncertainty feels like something that needs to be accounted for - as we do, for example, in classic A/B test where we have both treated and control outcomes and we run a statistical test on the difference between them based on both their distribution.

So I wonder if I should somehow try to measure the uncertainty in my observed treatment revenue and compare its distribution to the counterfactual distribution (effectively running a test for the difference in means between treatment and synthetic control). Any suggestions on whether this is a better approach indeed?